# Verificar link dependendo do conteúdo inicia query

Tags: javascript, jquery

Preciso carregar um "fake loader" quando um link no menu é acionado, porém neste menu alguns links são vazios `<a href="javascript:;">` ou `<a href="#">`, preciso identificar apenas estes via javascript e não abrir o "loader".

Não posso adicionar nada no menu (id, classe, etc...).

```js
$( "a" ).click(function() {
  $( "#loader" ).fadeIn( "slow" );
});
```

```css
#loader{ width: 100%; height:100%; display: none; background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.6); position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0; z-index: 2 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="loader"><img src="images/loader.gif" width="100px" height="100px" style="margin-left: 45%; margin-top: 20%;" /></div> 


<nav>
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Vazio 1</a> <- Não pode Funcionar</li>
  <li><a href="javascript:;">Vazio 2</a> <- Não pode Funcionar</li>
  <li><a href="linkcerto">Link correto</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

O motivo do problema é o desenvolvedor back-end do site em que estou mexendo simplesmente ter sumido, por isso não tenho como mexer no código-fonte  diretamente, apenas no java-script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Faça uma condição para chamar o loader...

```js
$( "a" ).click(function() {
if($(this).attr("href") != "javascript:;" && $(this).attr("href") != "#") {
  $( "#loader" ).fadeIn( "slow" );
}
});
```

```css
#loader{ width: 100%; height:100%; display: none; background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.6); position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0; z-index: 2 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="loader"><img src="images/loader.gif" width="100px" height="100px" style="margin-left: 45%; margin-top: 20%;" /></div> 


<nav>
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Vazio 1</a> <- Não pode Funcionar</li>
  <li><a href="javascript:;">Vazio 2</a> <- Não pode Funcionar</li>
  <li><a href="linkcerto">Link correto</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Perfeito!
Obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

Rodrigo.
Tente por isso no seu JS (não sei se vai funcionar, não testei.

```
$( "a" ).click(function() {
     if (("a").val() != "Vazio 1" || ("a").val() != "Vazio 2")
     {
        $( "#loader" ).fadeIn( "slow" );
     }
});
```

Comment: Não entendi muito bem o que quer fazer.
mas no seu JS você está pegando o link para todos os elementos que tem a tag <code>a</code> por isso dispara.
Coloque um ID nos itens e chame o ID específico.
Seria isso?

Comment: acho que seria mais interessante você demonstrar (via código) a solução

Comment: Então, o problema é que não tenho como editar o "html" pois o back-end bloqueou o alteração dos arquivos no ftp.
Só estou com permissão para editar os ".js" e ".css".

Outros itens que já possuem ID bloqueei, os links em questão não posso adicionar ID, classe ou qualquer outro elemento.

Por este motivo preciso identificar o que tem as urls citadas e não ativar a função.

Comment: Rodrigo.Não tem como pegar esse arquivo no FTP, fazer a alteração e substituir?

Comment: Não funcionou.
Um coisa importante é que as palavras "vazio 1" e "vazio 2" são simbólicas, os links sim não reais.

utilizando o seu código seria  meio que isso:

Comment: $( "a" ).click(function() {
     if (("a").val() != "#" || ("a").val() != "javascript:;")
     {
        $( "#loader" ).fadeIn( "slow" );
     }
});

Comment: Meso assim não funcionou.